# How to make text and its picture pop up together in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I am using Beamer to make a presentation. I wish to make the text and its corresponding picture showing up simultaneously.

Currently, I am able to show the pictures in the frame together with the texts with the help of `minipage`, but they overlap and are always static there from the beginning to the end. Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Background}

\begin{minipage}[0.2\textheight]{\textwidth}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1\pause
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 1\pause
    \item 2\pause
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
\rule{50pt}{50pt}% pic corresponding to 1.1
\rule{50pt}{50pt}% pic corresponding to 1.2
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{minipage}


\end{frame}
\end{document}​
```

The desired effect should be...

- 1 pops up
- 1.1 pops up together with pic1
- 1.2 pops up together with pic2

Pic1 can either disappear or remain there, when pic2 comes, as long as pic2 is visible.

How can I make it happen?

Comment: Have a look at section 9 of the manual, there are also other overlay commands.

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried but failed... *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you would like to have the picture appear when 1.1 appears, and then the second picture replace it when 1.2 appears.  This can be done using the `\alt` command and the slide specification given by `<` and `>` instead of `\pause`.  Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\picone}{{\color{red}\rule{50pt}{50pt}}}
\newcommand{\pictwo}{{\color{green}\rule{50pt}{50pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Background}

\begin{minipage}[0.2\textheight]{\textwidth}
\begin{columns}[T]

\begin{column}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> 1
\begin{enumerate}
\item<3-> 1
\item<4-> 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
\alt<1-2>{}{\alt<3>{\picone}{\pictwo}}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have included the `color` package to make the change of picture visible.

If you would like the first picture to stay when the second appear, then you could replace

```
\alt<1-2>{}{\alt<3>{\picone}{\pictwo}}
```

by

```
\onslide<3->{\picone}
\onslide<4->{\pictwo}
```

I hope this was the kind of solution you where looking for.

**EDIT**

In beamer you can usually use `<n-m>` on most commands to specify when they should appear in the frame.  As one might suspect, `n` and `m` indicates in interval, but one of then might be left out, so that `<n-`> and `<-m>` means from `n` and forth and until `m` respectively.  Also you can write `<n>` if it is only on slide `n` you want the thing to appear.  These things can be combined with comma seperated lists, so that `<1,4->` means on slide 1 plus slide 4 and forth.

The command `\alt` displays one thing and then alters (hence the name I guess) it to something else on the specified slides.  As an example

```
\alt<2-3>{first}{second}
```

displyas `first` on slide 2 and 3 and `second` on the rest.

What I did was to make nested `\alt`'s, so to make it possible to change between three different things (nothing, picture 1 and picture 2).  Thus if you wanted an extra picture to appear after number two, you replace

```
\alt<1-2>{}{\alt<3>{\picone}{\pictwo}}
```

by

```
\alt<1-2>{}{\alt<3>{\picone}{\alt<4>{\pictwo}{\picthree}}}
```

In this way you can continue with as many pictures as you want.

Comment: Yes! Very close. But could you please elaborate on the <2-> part? How does the picture correspond to each item?

Comment: What if I have three pictures?

Comment: Please kindly help, I am staying overnight to finish my presentation slides. It is now 4:43am. Please help!

Comment: @FarticlePilter: I was writing the elaboration, but firefox was acting up, so I could not leave comments :)  Hope it helps.

Comment: You saved my life! This teaches me a lot! I sincerely appreciate your help! Thanks!